# Decoding error with my Python function

Tags: python, unicode

I am using the Robot framework to automate some HTTP POST related tests. I wrote a custom Python library that has a function to do a HTTP POST. It looks like this:

```
# This function will do a http post and return the json response
def Http_Post_using_python(json_dict,url):
    post_data = json_dict.encode('utf-8')
    headers = {}
    headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    h = httplib2.Http()
    resp, content = h.request(url,'POST',post_data,headers)
    return resp, content
```

This works fine as long as I am not using any Unicode characters. When I have Unicode characters in the `json_dict` variable (for example, 메시지), it fails with this error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xeb in position 164: ordinal not in range(128)

I am running Python 2.7.3 on Windows 7. I saw several related questions, but I have not been able to resolve the issue. I am new to Python and programming, so any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Please include the *full* traceback.

Comment: Have you tried post_data = unicode(json_dict, encoding="utf-8")? I don't really have very clear how the encoding/decodings/parsings work (that's why this is a comment and not an answer) but maybe it'll help...

Comment: @BorrajaX `unicode(json_dict, encoding="utf-8")` will be exactly the opposite of what OP wants — they want a `str`, *not* a `unicode`.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting this error because `json_dict` is a `str`, not a `unicode`. Without knowing anything else about the application, a simple solution would be:

```
if isinstance(json_dict, unicode):
    json_dict = json_dict.encode("utf-8")
post_data = json_dict
```

However, if you're using `json.dumps(…)` to create the `json_dict`, then you don't need to encode it – that will be done by `json.dumps(…)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/):

```
requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
```

It will deal with the encodings for you.

---

You're getting an error because of Python 2's automatic encoding/decoding, which is basically a bug and was fixed in Python 3. In brief, Python 2's `str` objects are really "bytes", and the right way to handle string data is in a `unicode` object. Since `unicode`s were introduced later, Python 2 will automatically try to convert between them and strings when you get them confused. To do so it needs to know an encoding; since you don't specify one, it defaults to `ascii` which doesn't have the characters needed.

Why is Python automatically trying to decode for you? Because you're calling `.encode()` on a `str` object. It's already encoded, so Python first tries to decode it for you, and guesses the `ascii` encoding.

---

You should read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
#coding=utf-8
test = "메시지" 
test.decode('utf8')
```

In the line `#coding=utf-8` i just set the file encoding to UTF-8 (to be able to write "메시지").

You need to decode the string into utf-8. [decode method documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.decode)

Comment: Setting a source code encoding only applies to *reading* the source code, especially literals. It does *not* magically solve any other unicode - byte conversions.